# Custom xml layout inflater in Scrollview issue

Tags: android, listview, layout, server, custom-controls

I'm successfully inflating my custom XML layout into my code, it gets shown in the app based on the number of items of an array, although I get only the first item's data (an avatar image and its username text), from the 2nd items on, I get the default layout's image and text, here's my code:

```
 //-----------------------------------------------
// MARK - QUERY MOMENTS
//-----------------------------------------------
void queryMoments() {
    Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "QUERY MOMENTS...");

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    List<String>currUserObjID = new ArrayList<>();
    currUserObjID.add(currentUser.getObjectId());

    // Clear moments array
    momentsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // Launch query
    ParseQuery<ParseObject>query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Configurations.MOMENTS_CLASS_NAME);
    query.whereContainedIn(Configurations.MOMENTS_FOLLOWED_BY, currUserObjID);
    query.orderByDescending(Configurations.MOMENTS_CREATED_AT);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                // Some Moment exists
                if (objects.size() != 0) {
                    momentsArray = objects;

                    // Scrollview and embedded Layout
                    final HorizontalScrollView sv = findViewById(R.id.hMomentsScrollView);
                    final LinearLayout momentsLayout = findViewById(R.id.hMomentsLayout);
                    momentsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    momentsLayout.removeAllViews();

                    for (int i=0; i<momentsArray.size(); i++) {
                        final ParseObject mObj = objects.get(i);

                        // Get userPointer
                        mObj.getParseObject(Configurations.MOMENTS_USER_POINTER).fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(final ParseObject userPointer, ParseException e) {


                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                momentsLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.moment_layout, sv, false));


                                // ------------------------------------------------
                                // MARK: - WATCH MOMENT'S VIDEO BUTTON
                                // ------------------------------------------------
                                CircleImageView avImg = findViewById(R.id.mlAvatarImg);
                                Configurations.getParseImage(avImg, userPointer, Configurations.USER_AVATAR);

                                avImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, WatchVideo.class);
                                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                        extras.putString("objectID", mObj.getObjectId());
                                        i.putExtras(extras);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                }});

                                // Username Txt
                                TextView uTxt = findViewById(R.id.mlUsernameTxt);
                                uTxt.setTypeface(Configurations.osItalic);
                                uTxt.setText(userPointer.getString(Configurations.USER_USERNAME));

                        }});// end userPointer

                    }// ./For loop

        // error
        } else { Configurations.simpleAlert(e.getMessage(),ctx); }

    }}});// ./ query
```

And here's my **moment_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/mlAvatarImg"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/main_color"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mlUsernameTxt"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mlAvatarImg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="•••"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ScrollView XML code:

```
   <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hMomentsScrollView"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/hMomentsLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

So, let's pretend my **momentsArray** has 2 items (I get them correctly from the Logcat), one if **johndoe**, the other one is **sarahdoe**. What I get is the image and username of **johndoe**, which is the 1st array's item, then I get an empty ImageView and TextView view as 2nd item, although my Logcat shows **sarahdoe** as 2nd item.

I've tried with more items, same result, from the 2nd items on, they all show the default ImageView and textView.

Am I doing something wrong in the code above? Here's a screenshot of what I get:

[image]

Comment: Show us XML of your layout to understand what is going on.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis thanks, I've added my XML layout's code

Comment: Provide HorizontalScrollView XML. Thanks.

Comment: change your RelativeLayout from  android:layout_height="match_parent" to  android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Comment: @urvijoshi it doesn't matter, it's not about the layout size, but data :)

Comment: @TomasJablonskis I've also added a screenshot of what i get, no data from the 2nd row on, only the default xml layout. the first layout show image and data from the server

Comment: can you please share the full code of your java class.? @xscoder

Comment: @urvijoshi I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From information you have provided I can make an assumption that you are *reinventing the wheel*.

---

What you need to do to archive horizontal scroll behaviour of list of views is to use **RecyclerView** in horizontal configuration and use **RecyclerView Adapter** to inflate items into it with corresponding information. Where to get started can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

P.S. to set RecyclerView to scroll horizontally you can specify "orientation" property in XML like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

---

Approach mentioned above is not only the correct way of doing it, but also performant when it comes to large list of items to be displayed.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just wanted to use a ScrollView so I'll just create Views programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As said above - don't reinvent the wheel and use RecyclerView.

But in current code the point is that you are trying to get each placeholder from root scroll view but with same id, which will always return first child

```
findViewById(R.id.mlUsernameTxt)
```

You should do something like this instead:

```
View placeholder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.moment_layout, momentsLayout, false);
momentsLayout.addView(placeholder)
TextView uTxt = placeholder.findViewById(R.id.mlUsernameTxt);
```